# Highlight.js fails at Haskell?

Tags: javascript, css, haskell, syntax

I use `Highlight.js` at [my Site](http://tekkkz.com/posts/articles/arch_installation.html) with the `Monokai.css` Theme.
See more:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/styles/monokai.css">
<script src="../../js/highlight.pack.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

Bit like you can see, something went wrong.

```
<pre>
  <code class="haskell">
    {-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
    euclid :: Int -> Int -> Int
    euclid a b
      | a == 0    = b
      | b == 0    = a
      | a > b     = euclid (a-b) b
      | otherwise = euclid a (b-a)
  </code>
</pre>
```

Why is it not shown correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my DOM explorer I see this turns into

```
<code class="haskell hljs">
        <span class="hljs-pragma">{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}</span>
        euclid :: <span class="hljs-type">Int</span> -&gt; <span class="hljs-type">Int</span> -&gt; <span class="hljs-type">Int</span>
        euclid a b
          | a == <span class="hljs-number">0</span>    = b
          | b == <span class="hljs-number">0</span>    = a
          | a &gt; b     = euclid (a-b) b
          | otherwise = euclid a (b-a)

      </code>
```

Those spans have the following rule from line 143 in http://tekkkz.com/css/style.css applied, which messes up their size and placement. Disabling that makes it look fine to me.

```
.content span {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
```